# New Token is Fetched Whenever New Thread is Added while using MSAL Authentication Provider with Micrsoft Graph SDK and Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am developing an Azure Function app. The function is using Microsoft Graph SDK to consume Graph. It uses MSAL Authentication Provider.

I have implemented Graph Service Client as a static object and made sure that only one instance of GraphServiceClient exists for the app. While the single instance of Azure Function is executing, the token remains the same for various calls to the Graph and only gets updated when it expires. The token and new token are fetched by **AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)** method.

However, whenever a new instance of azure function is added e.g. I call the function two or more times quickly one after another, the token is updated for each call or whenever a new instance is added.
I have also tried to implement it as explained in this post https://github.com/BrianTJackett/BTJ.CSAdvent.AZFunc but by keeping the graph client static. The result is the same.

**What I want is to keep the same token to be used with all the instances of azure function and only get new token when the current one is about to expire. Is there any way that this can be achieved?**

This is for client credentials flow.

Here is my code:

```
public class MSGraphAuth
{
    private static MSGraphAuth _graphAuth;
    private static GraphServiceClient _graphClient;
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    private MSGraphAuth() { }

    public static MSGraphAuth GraphAuth
    {
        get
        {
            if (_graphAuth == null)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (_graphAuth == null)
                    {
                        _graphAuth = new MSGraphAuth();
                        _graphAuth.InitializeGraphClient();
                    }
                }
            }

            return _graphAuth;
        }
    }

    public GraphServiceClient GraphClient
    {
        get
        {
            return _graphClient;
        }
    }

    void InitializeGraphClient()
    {
        string authority = "{authority}";

        IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(AppSettings.MSGRAPHCLIENTID)
        .WithAuthority(authority)
        .WithClientSecret(AppSettings.MSGRAPHCLIENTSECRET)
        .Build();

        _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
        {

            var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            var authResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            requestMessage
                .Headers
                .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, may I know if your problem was solved ?

Comment: Hi, Hury. I haven't been able to try it out yet as I didn't get the chance. Sorry for the delay, but I will update as soon as I have tried it out.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, it is not easy for us to implement singleton instance of `GraphServiceClient` in azure function. But we can do it by another workaround, please refer to the solution below:

We can get the token at first time and set it in environment variable. When next function request (or other function instances request) want to use access token, it just need to get the token from environment variable. We can implement it by the code below in function.

```
string tokenVal = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("token");
if (tokenVal != null) {
    log.LogInformation("do the operations what you want by access token");
}else {
    log.LogInformation("request for a new token and set it in environment variable, then use the token to do the what you want");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("token", "token_value");
}
```

For the expiration of the token, we can get the expire date by `authResult.ExpiresOn` and also set it in environment variable at first time. Then we can compare it with current date in function code, if the access token expire, request for another token and set it in environment variable(also set the new expire date in environment variable). You can implement the compare date part and add it to the "**if**" condition in the code above (please pay attention to the time zone of the date get from `authResult.ExpiresOn`).

By the way, the access token and expire date can be set in environment, but they will not show in application setting of your function app. **And if restart the function app, they will be lost**.